# Convertir consulta a JQuery y ajax

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hola tengo un proyecto MVC y estoy utilizando la base de datos de un servidor. En el proyecto hago las consulta con javascript, y sucede que tengo un input para seleccionar la fecha en un calendario y un option para seleccionar el nombre de un usuario ya cargado desde la base de datos.

Mi pregunta es cómo mostrar los demás campos del usuario (en el div llamado "datos") de acuerdo al nombre y la fecha seleccionados al dar click en el botón ver...

En otras palabras, como traducir:
    "Select * from tabla where user ="+inputUser+" and fecha ="+inputfecha+"'";
en lenguaje javascript y/o ajax.
La verdad no tengo mucha idea
aquí dejo mi código html:

```html
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <select class="form-control" name="IdGestor">
  <option></option>
  @{
  if (Model.UsersList != null)
  {
  foreach (Users users in Model.UsersList)
  {
  <option value="@gestores.id">@users.Nombre</option>
  }
  }
  else
  {
  <option value="0"> No hay usuarios </option>
  }
  }
  </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="Fecha" placeholder="Fecha" required pattern="[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}" />
  <span class="validity"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" id="ver" style="font-size:20px" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" title="Ver">
 <span class="fa fa-search">Ver</span>
 </a>
 </div>

 
 <div id="datos"></div>
```

Comment: deberías parametrizar la consulta sql en vez de concatenar la información introducida por el usuario

Answer (score 0):

No entendí bien a tu pregunta, si seleccion un usuario del select, me tiene que mostrar los demas datos dentro del div datos no? tienes que recorrer el arreglo con un for parecido al que tienes al principio:

```
for(user as users){
   <li><?php echo user->nombre; ?></li>
   <li><?php echo user->apellido; ?></li>
}
```

Algo parecido a ello claro en users almacenas todo el registro que obtengas de la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer este tipo de cosas normalmente tienes que construir un endpoint REST que reciba el user_id y la fecha; y retorne la información que necesitas en algún formato, puede ser xml, json o incluso html listo para insertar directamente en tu div #datos. Lo recomendable es que uses json y construyas el html con javascript para luego insertarlo dentro de tu div #datos.

Otra solución más chapucera pero sencilla, en caso que sea un ejercicio solamente, sería cargar absolutamente toda la información de todos los usuarios en el html en forma de divs que tengan como id el user_id y la fecha. Y los tengas todos ocultos. Por ejemplo:

```
<div id="user_123_20181017" style="display: none">...</div>
<div id="user_123_20181018" style="display: none">...</div>
<div id="user_456_20181018" style="display: none">...</div>
<div id="user_789_20181018" style="display: none">...</div>
```

Y que en el evento onclick decidas mostrar el div correspondiente.

En cualquier caso, la solución no es trivial y sería difícil plasmarla eficientemente por aquí.